# How can I reproduce arduino's shiftOut( ) fonction on a raspberry pi 3+ in C langage?

Tags: raspbian, arduino, c

Can someone help me to reproduce arduino's shiftOut( ) fonction on a raspberry pi 3+ in C langage?
Preferably using bcm2835 library.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. It would be kind to provide synopsis and description of the function. Think of it that way, you could include it in your answer (*write once*) and save potential readers / answerers the time and effort to dig it up themselfes (*read often*).

Comment: Pls confirm if following is the function you like. The other link is for microPython. It is usually easier to test with python then to C.
Arduino shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, bitOrder, value) Function
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/shiftout/

MicroPython ShiftOut Method - mhepp 2017jul12
https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=3573  You may also like to let use know if you would prefer to adapt SPI. or use HC595 which is the most popular for higher speed and not over loading Rpi: 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=123237

Answer (score 0):

As you will have to act on the GPIO I recommand you go with wiring pi. 
If you are coming from the Arduino world you will recognise commands.

Wiring Pi, is a Wiring library, like on Arduino with DigitalWrite() but for Raspberry.

Of course if you don't know how works a shift register maybe you should take a look at the datasheet of something like the 74HC595.